# Second unit test always fails. AngularJS, Mocha, Chai

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to learn how to do unit tests and I have a simple test scenario with two cases, I'll show you the code immediately.
The first test runs fine, but the second one gives me this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.2/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20stringI/<@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:6:423
rb@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:22:108
Ra@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:22:195
eb.$$annotate@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:189:216
angular.injector.$$annotate@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2461:12
e@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:40:306
workFn/<@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2544:13
n@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:7:342
workFn@http://localhost:63342/happiness_module/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2533:9
```

Here is the test.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">

    <!-- library scripts -->
    <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        mocha.setup({
            "ui": "bdd",
            "reporter": "html"
        });
    </script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- project scripts -->
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/services/SimpleService.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/MyController.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
<script>
    mocha.run();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular
    .module('app', []);
```

MyController:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyController', [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        return 10;
    }
    $scope.doOtherThing = function() {
        return 11;
    }
}]);
```

test.js:

```
window.assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;

beforeEach(module('app'));
describe('MyController', function () {
    var ctrl,
        scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('MyController', {$scope: scope});
    }));
    describe('First Test', function() {
        it('Do something should be 10', function () {
            var result = scope.doSomething();
            expect(result).to.equal(10);
        });
    });

    describe('Second Test', function() {
        it('Do another thing should be 11', function () {
            var result = scope.doOtherThing();
            expect(result).to.equal(11);

        });
    });

});
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?